# Creating a toolbar component to divide toolbar in 2 pieces

Tags: ckeditor5

I am trying to divide my CKEditor 5 toolbar in two pieces, far apart from each other. Here's my actual toolbar :

[image]

With the following html rendered code :

[image]

What I would like to is something like this :

```
toolbar: [
  'heading',
  'bold',
  'italic',
  'underline',
  '=', // this is the delimiter 
  'alignment:left',
  'alignment:right',
  'alignment:center'
],
```

And I want to generate this code based on that delimiter :

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between;">
    <div>
        <!-- part 1 before the = -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- part 2 after the = -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out how to achieve this. Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The current [`ToolbarView`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_toolbar_toolbarview-ToolbarView.html) doesn't support splitting into multiple lines.

I can think of two quite straightforward choices:

1. Extend [`ToolbarView`](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/blob/master/src/toolbar/toolbarview.js) so it can do something like this and either use it directly in your own [`Editor`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editor-Editor.html) class or inject it instead of the original `ToolarView` just like [you can inject your own icons](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#how-to-customize-the-ckeditor-5-icons).
2. [Fill](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_toolbar_toolbarview-ToolbarView.html#function-fillFromConfig) two separate toolbar instances and use them in your own editor class.

BTW, the simplest editor implementation you can use as a base is the [`DecoupledEditor`](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-decoupled) which you can for instance see here: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/examples/builds/document-editor.html

Answer (score 0):

This issue is tracked in https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/6146 add thumbs up to the ticket if you would like this feature to be implemented.